# Работа с javax.comm в linux

Tags: java, linux

Привет. Кто-нибудь знает, как правильно установить javax.comm в ubuntu? Мне эта библиотека нужна для работы с COM-портами. В инете натыкался на старые туториалы. Ещё, я так понимаю, мне нужно установить RXTX. Может кто-нить знает актуальные туториалы по установке этого добра в линуксе? Линканите или расскажите плиз.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного уточню предыдущего автора. :)

1. Перейти по ссылке загрузки [Java Communication API Download](https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_SMI-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductRef=JAVACOMM-3.0.1-LX-SP-G-F@CDS-CDS_SMI) (видна на странице [Java Communications](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html)).
2. Зарегистрироваться.
3. Скачать архив для платформы Linux.
4. В архиве ознакомиться с инструкцией `docs/html/platform/linux/PlatformSpecific.html` и выполнить ее по шагам.

Answer (score 0):

https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_SMI-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewFilteredProducts-SingleVariationTypeFilter

выбираете прлатформу. Качаете. Распаковываете. Папка docs - вся документация